# PHP PDO changes remote host to local hostname

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to connect to a remote mysql server using PDO. However, regardless of the hostname or ip address i supply in the dsn, when the script is run it always reverts the address to the hostname of the local server where the webserver is running.

Google suggests this could be something to do with SELinux and apaches ability to connect to remote databases, however i have SELinux disabled.

Distro: Ubuntu 11.04 x64

Apache version: 2.2.17

PHP Version: PHP 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.11 with Suhosin-Patch (cli)

Edit:

Added code as requested. Though i dont believe this is an issue with my coding as it works fine on the local server, but doesnt allow remote connection.

```
public function db_connect($driver, $dbhost, $dbname, $user, $pass) {
    $dsn = $driver . ':host=' . $dbhost . ';dbname=' . $dbname;
    try {
        $this->DB = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
    }
    catch (PDOException $err) {
        print 'Database Connection Failed: ' . $err->getMessage();
        die();
    }
}

$remote_db = new DB('mysql', 'remote_server.domain.tld', 'database_name', 'user_name', 'password');
```

This is the error message i am receiving.

> Database Connection Failed: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user_name'@'local_server.domain.tld' (using password: YES)

Comment: You haven't posted any code here, so how can we help you?

Comment: Provided relevant code as needed. Though i do not believe this to be an issue with my code as it works perfectly via. the local server where i have test data. I'm now wanting to use the live data which is on the remote server.

Comment: @WadeUrry, Code is always relevant for questions like this.

Comment: Have you enabled remote access ? http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database-remotely

Answer (score 2):

That error isn't saying you are connected to `local_server.domain.tld`, it's simply stating that that's where you are connecting **from**.  The error must have to do with your GRANTs, or other authentication problem.